# Why is lock.notifyAll not waking up thread waiting

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a BluetoothManager that contains a while loop to detect bluetooth state changes. If bluetooth is off, I want to enable and wait until the lock is notifiy from inside the runnable that the bluetooth is on again. The issue that I am facing is that when I lock.wait the whole thread is waiting and the while loop inside the runnable is no longer executing. Can someone explain why this is happening? I know I can achieve similar functionality using a broadcast receiver but I want to understand why my lock wait/notify is not working.

```
    public class BluetoothManager implements BluetoothA2DPRequester.Callback {

    private Object lock = new Object();

    public BluetoothManager(Handler handler, BluetoothManagerListener listener) {

        Handler phandler = new Handler();
        Runnable prunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Lock is notified about access again.");
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                      handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                      return;
                } else {
                    phandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                    enableBluetooth()
                }

            }
        };
        phandler.post(prunnable);

    }


    public void enableBluetooth() {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        } else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // Bluetooth is not enabled
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyApplication.getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                synchronized (lock) {
                    try {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Lock is released. Waiting for Bluetooth to turn on.");
                        lock.wait(); // wait until bluetooth is on // I am getting stucked here
                        Log.i(TAG, "Lock is gained again.");
                        isBluetoothOn = true;
                        onBluetoothConnected();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        } else {
            isBluetoothOn = true;
            onBluetoothConnected();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: *Why is lock.notifyAll not waking up thread waiting* probably because there is no `notifyAll` in your code.

Comment: The output is the same with `notifyAll`

Comment: Stuck at this log `Lock is released. Waiting for bluetooth to turn on.`

Comment: order of execution?

Comment: I just call BluetoothManager() from another class instance. As such:

     `btManager = new BluetoothManager(handler, btListener);`

Comment: great, and is your `prunnable` even running?

Comment: Yes, it runs the first time, after calling the enableBluetooth() the thread is getting blocked.

Comment: and again, order of execution?

Comment: In my MainService class I call this function 
`startBluetoothManager(){
        btManager = new BluetoothManager(handler, btListener);
}`

then in the BluetoothManager constructor I call phandler.post(prunnable); which check if bluetooth is enabled, after the first check and the bluetooth was off, we hit the else condition and call `enableBluetooth()` after that the thread get blocked and we don't get the notify

Comment: and logs comes in the order you would like, first *Waiting for Bluetooth to turn on.* then *Lock is notified about access again.* right?

Comment: I am getting only _Waiting for Bluetooth to turn on_ because after calling enableBluetooth the first time and enabling the bluetooth, the thread is getting blocked and the prunnable stops.

Comment: So no notification at all, case closed.

Comment: To me you are waiting on handler thread and expect it to notify itself.

Comment: I am synchronizing on the lock, why when I call lock.wait is blocking the whole thread and the handler?

Comment: Object#wait block current thread.

Comment: From docs: 
*Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.* So yeah, u are literally block the thread that executes tasks submitted to that handler

Comment: so If calling lock.wait blocks the current thread and we can't call lock.notify from another thread, how to relinquish the lock?

Comment: by calling it from another thread. You try to do it from the same thread.

Comment: Re, "...the whole thread is waiting..." What do you mean, _whole_ thread? A thread either is waiting or it is executing instructions. A thread doesn't have parts. It sounds as if you do not have a strong idea of what a thread actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If calling lock.wait blocks the current thread and we can't call lock.notify from another thread, how to relinquish the lock?

You can't.

`lock.wait()` returns when some *other* thread calls `lock.notify()` or `lock.notifyAll()`. Except in case of the hypothetical spurious wakeup,* the `wait()` call will not return for any other reason.

Also of note, `lock.notify()` and `lock.notifyAll()` do absolutely *nothing* unless the other thread is *already* waiting. A common newbie mistake is to have a race between some thread P that calls `notify()` and some thread C that calls `wait()`. If thread C wins the race, then the `notify()` wakes it up and everything is fine, but if thread P wins the race, then thread C has missed the notification, and it ends up waiting forever for a second notification that never arrives.

---

P.S., (Hope you notice this update because apparently you already have accepted my answer.)

Look into the [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) class. A semaphore is like a blocking queue of virtual, informationless tokens. One thread can call `semaphore.release()` to add a token to the queue. Another thread can call `semaphore.acquire()` to take a token from the queue, but if the queue is empty, then the `acquire()` call will *wait* until some other thread `release()`s a token for it to take.

This may be helpful to you, because unlike wait/notify, a semaphore *remembers* how many tokens are in the queue. You can fix my example of the race condition between thread P and thread C (above) by using a semaphore instead of wait/notify.  If thread C wins the race, it will wait until thread P catches up and releases a token. But, if thread P wins the race, then the semaphore will hold the token until thread C catches up. Thread C can then acquire it, and it will not be blocked.

---

* [search this page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) for more about *spurious wakeup.*

Comment: @CharlesSemaan, I hope you notice the information about `Semaphore` that I added to my answer, above.